# Problem installing VirtualBox on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, install, virtualbox

I'm trying to install VirtualBox 6.0.15 on my mid-2010 MacBook Pro 13" with High Sierra on it.  The installer gets to the "Running package scripts" with "Time remaining: less than a minute" - and then hangs.  Waiting for 30 minutes does nothing.  In the console, I can see in the install.log:

```
2020-01-24 22:15:44+00 Cloud installd[27429]: PackageKit: ----- Begin install -----
2020-01-24 22:15:44+00 Cloud installd[27429]: PackageKit: request=PKInstallRequest <4 packages, destination=/>
2020-01-24 22:15:44+00 Cloud installd[27429]: PackageKit: packages=(
2020-01-24 22:15:45+00 Cloud installd[27429]: PackageKit: Extracting file:///Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VBoxKEXTs.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/46764F46-7766-4183-854A-79216CB03C11.activeSandbox/Root/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox, uid=0)
2020-01-24 22:15:47+00 Cloud installd[27429]: PackageKit: Extracting file:///Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VirtualBox.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/46764F46-7766-4183-854A-79216CB03C11.activeSandbox/Root/Applications, uid=0)
2020-01-24 22:15:52+00 Cloud installd[27429]: PackageKit: Extracting file:///Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VirtualBoxCLI.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/46764F46-7766-4183-854A-79216CB03C11.activeSandbox/Root/usr/local/bin, uid=0)
2020-01-24 22:15:52+00 Cloud installd[27429]: PackageKit: Extracting file:///Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#OSXFuseCore.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/46764F46-7766-4183-854A-79216CB03C11.activeSandbox/Root, uid=0)
2020-01-24 22:15:52+00 Cloud installd[27429]: PackageKit: prevent user idle system sleep
2020-01-24 22:15:52+00 Cloud installd[27429]: PackageKit: suspending backupd
2020-01-24 22:15:52+00 Cloud installd[27429]: PackageKit: Executing script "./preflight" in /private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.fRMY1G/Scripts/org.virtualbox.pkg.virtualbox.8bFgh6
2020-01-24 22:15:52+00 Cloud installd[27429]: PackageKit: Executing script "./preinstall" in /private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.fRMY1G/Scripts/com.github.osxfuse.pkg.Core.3YlHpP
2020-01-24 22:15:53+00 Cloud installd[27429]: PackageKit: Using trashcan path /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/PKInstallSandboxTrash/46764F46-7766-4183-854A-79216CB03C11.sandboxTrash for sandbox /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/46764F46-7766-4183-854A-79216CB03C11.activeSandbox
2020-01-24 22:15:54+00 Cloud installd[27429]: PackageKit: Shoving /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/46764F46-7766-4183-854A-79216CB03C11.activeSandbox/Root (3 items) to /
2020-01-24 22:15:54+00 Cloud installd[27429]: PackageKit: Executing script "./postflight" in /private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.fRMY1G/Scripts/org.virtualbox.pkg.vboxkexts.fPelJc
2020-01-24 22:15:54+00 Cloud installd[27429]: ./postflight: /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.virtualbox.startup.plist
```

And that's it! Nothing further in the log - and the installation is simply hanging. How can I complete the installation?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so in desperation I left it overnight - and it did complete.  Looking at the logs, it took about 3 hours from that line to the next one in the log.  Very bizarre, but it's done.

Comment: You may want to discuss this in the VirtualBox forums.  It might be unknown behavoir.